# Can I use DataAnnotations to custom validate an object in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, data-annotations

Is it possible to use `DataAnnotations` on an object and then .. programmatically, test to see if that object is `Valid` or not?

I'm not using `MVC3` or `ModelBinding` or `ASP.NET` .. but a `WinForms` app.

Is this possible?

eg.

```
if (foo.IsValid) ? Hi() : Bye();
```

and the IsValid somehow checks each property that has `DataAnnotations` on em, or something. ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Validator` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I know SLaks has answered my question, but [here is another good, detailed description of the solution](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx) from Scott Allen :)